# How do I construct a (non-static) Java inner class from Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, inner-classes

If I have a class with an inner class like this:

```
public class A {
    class B { //note, no modifier on class or constructor
      B(String c) {System.out.println(c);}
    }
}
```

From Java (in the same package) I can do this:

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a. new B("test")); //crazy syntax!
    }
}
```

But in Groovy, that doesn't work. So how do I construct a new B [from a groovy class in the same package]?

Comment: I've always thought that while creating an instance of A, you are creating an instance of B automatically

Comment: @JClassic no, instantiating A will not create an instance of B automatically

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

```
def a = new A()
A.B.newInstance(a, "foo")
```

And also like this:

```
def a = new A()
new A.B(a, "foo")
```

If the Java code is under your control rather than being an external library I'd far rather use a factory method, though.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(new B(a, "test")); //crazy syntax!
```

Comment: The groovy 1.7 release notes cover why this syntax is the case when support for inner classes were added: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.7+release+notes

Comment: I couldn't get it to work without qualifying `B` –  `new A.B(a, "test")` (using Groovy 2.3.9)

Comment: This doesn't work. I get "Groovyc: unable to resolve class B"